# How to send a Return key in an already existing screen session on MacOS?

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, gnu-screen

First, I create a session by typing `screen -S test1`, then I detach and type `screen -S test1 -p 0 -X stuff "ls^M"`. This doesn't work, it just prints the characters "ls^M" in my session.

Comment: ^M is supposed be the Enter key code... Probably works on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details I don't know why it does not work for you but you can try other ways:

```
screen -S session -X -p 0 stuff  "echo hello\r"
# OR 
screen -S session -X -p 0 stuff $'echo world\r'
```

Comment: The second works, thank you very much (I removed the first). Any explanation?

Comment: it's weird. what's the version of your macos, screen and bash?

Comment: MacOS `Big Sur`, `Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06` (same value after a `brew install screen`), bash `3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: your screen (shipped with macos) is too old. it's still of 2006. brew installed screen should be `/usr/local/bin/screen` and it reports 2020 (`05-Feb-20`) on my macos.

Comment: just tried macos' `/usr/bin/screen` and confirmed it does not support `\r` and `^M`.

Comment: Oh I didn't restart my terminal, this is why I didn't see the update. Now the `^M`works (`screen -S test1 -p 0 -X stuff "ls^M"`).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (from @pynexj) is to simply update the screen shipped with MacOS:

```
brew install screen
```

Then restart the terminal.